# How to uninstall NTFS-free?

Tags: macos, ntfs

I'm a pc user that started using OS X a while ago.

I installed ntfs-free to be able to write in my external NTFS devices and it worked fine, but with the last OS X update it stopped working.

In order to directly use the built-in OS X driver for NTFS partitions I want to uninstall ntfs-free because I'm afraid it is preventing the driver to run.

As far as I know there is no program or library deleting app or functionality in OS X, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the official uninstall script:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo rm -R /System/Library/Extensions/ntfs-free.kext
sudo rm -R /sbin/mount_ntfs-free
sudo rm -R /System/Library/Filesystems/ntfs-free.fs

if [ -f "/sbin/mount_ntfs_original" ]; then 
 sudo mv -f /sbin/mount_ntfs_original /sbin/mount_ntfs
fi
```

<sup>Source: http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/sourceforge/n/nt/ntfsfree/uninstall.sh</sup>